# Let $m$ and $n$ be integers. Then $n^3 – 2m – 2 \ne 0$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

I'm supposed to prove this using proof by contradiction, and I'm having a lot of trouble with it.

I understand that I'm supposed to assume the premise is true and the conclusion false, which would mean the new statement would be "Let m and n be integers. Then $n^3 - 2m - 2 = 0$. I've been trying to switch up the equation by adding $2m+2$ to the other side of the equation, but I really can't figure out what to do next. A hint that was given to me by my Professor was to try and contradict the premise by showing that $n, m$ or both are not integers.

Comment: $n=2,m=3$ ? The equation is can be satisfied by integers.

Comment: Pick any even $n$ and set $m=(n^3-2)/2$.

Comment: You cannot prove a false statement. Please check for typos.

Comment: @Peter; I've seen proofs for a problem similar to this one, except that the premise states that n and m are even integers. I see how you're supposed to prove that problem. Do you think the problem given has a typo? Because that is how it is stated in the homework assignment

Comment: As shown by Donald, the statement , as formulated, is clearly false.

Comment: There was in fact a typo with the problem; it was corrected by my Professor and I was able to come up with a solution. Thank you guys very much! (Edit: it was supposed to be that m and n are even integers, and by using proof by contradiction you can show that n is even but m is not, which provides us our contradiction.)

Comment: @kstoo Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$n^3 – 2m – 2 = 0\iff n^3=2(m+1)$$

thus $n^3$ must be even let $n=2k$

$$\iff n^3=2(m+1)\iff 8k^3=2(m+1)\iff 4k^3=m+1$$

$$\iff 4k^3-1=m$$

we don't find any contradiction and thus we can find infinitely many solutions: $$(n=2, m=3), (n=4, m=31), etc.$$